# How can I check an object which is equal object[0][]

Tags: c#, object, nullreferenceexception

I have an object named temp which is  initializing  with  an  function.
this function sametimes returns `object[0][]`,

[image]

this means null to me. but this is not null so I can not check this like this

```
if( temp == null)
```

I tried this

```
if( temp.Lengh == 0)
```

and I get err

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I want to set temp to null when the func returns object[0][].
how can I check temp is equal that?

Comment: You don't seem to give us correct information. `temp.Length == 0` should not throw an exception unless `temp` itself is `null`. What happens when you write `if (temp == null)`?

Comment: passes the condition, I mean, temp acts like it is not null

Comment: In that case I really doubt that `temp.Length` throws an exception. I bet you can have both cases: sometimes `temp == null` and sometimes `temp != null && temp.Length == 0`. Check for both like `if (temp == null || temp.Length == 0) ...`.

Comment: no, I did not do what u say @Thorsten Dittmar. there only one condition.As I sad to NathanAldenSr  if( temp.Lengh == 0) was working on my pc. then I host it to my server(my app is a web app) then It is start to throw null exception in the if condition

Comment: I know you didn't do what I suggested. Question is why? Obviously both `null` and `object[0][]` are possible results of `DB.GetRows(...)`. So...?

Answer (score 1):

The following code prints `False` and `0`, in succession:

```
var temp = new object[0][];

Console.WriteLine(temp == null);
Console.WriteLine(temp.Length);
```

The debugger doesn't lie; you have a bug in your program somewhere.

This code works as you requested:

```
var empty = new object[0][]; // Stand-in for a method's return value
...
var temp = empty.Length == 0 ? null : empty;
```

Comment: actually if( temp.Lengh == 0) was working on my pc. then I host it to my server(my app is a web app) then It is start to throw null exception in the if condition

Comment: There is some difference in your code when running in those environments, then. This is just logical deduction. I posted code that demonstrates that the runtime will treat `new object[0][]` as not null. If .NET were that buggy it would be unusable. :)

Comment: @kudra Then in the server environment the function call does not return `object[0][]`. It's as simple as that. Maybe there's an error accessing the DB and so the method returns `null` while on your PC DB access is possible but returns no records (== empty array)? Why not check `temp == null || temp.Length == 0`?

Comment: you're right.. I'll check all paths of my app and then reorganize the condition.. I was confused because of I am a jonior developer. Thanks again.